# Downloading list of audio from URL

Tags: java, android, audio, parse-platform

So I'm implementing audio Playlist app that imports audios from Parse.com, and when I retrieve them by streaming them directly from their URls, it took maybe one minute to play after clicking play button. 
So I don't want to use streaming from URL methods to play my audio from server because it makes it so slow. Instead I want to download list of audios from server (Parse.com) at once and then playing them by retrieving from sdcard.

I have the class that downloads single audio from single URL .. I want to edit the code to make it downloads more than one audio at once.

here is the class I have to download audio from URL.

```
class DownloadMusicfromInternet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private Context mContext;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;



public DownloadMusicfromInternet(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

// Download Music File from Internet
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
       URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // Get Music file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 10 * 1024);
        // Output stream to write file in SD card
        OutputStream output = new
```

*Also if you could help me in how to set a name for the audios, I don't want to write static name because I'm downloading more than one audio at a time .*

```
FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"+"how to put unique name for each audio here ?"+".mp3");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // Write data to file


   output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        // Flush output
        output.flush();
        // Close streams
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

// While Downloading Music File


// Once Music File is downloaded
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // Play the music
    playMusic();
}


// Play Music
protected void playMusic() {
    // Read Mp3 file present under SD card


    Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/"+"the same unique name that was set previously ! "+".mp3");
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mContext.getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        // Start playing the Music file
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Once Music is completed playing, enable the button
                // btnPlayMusic.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Music completed playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "URI cannot be accessed, permissed needed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Media Player is not in correct state", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "IO Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
}
```

and this is my adapter, and here is where my problem occurs and crashes my app. I don't know how to call ( DownloadMusicfromInternet ) more than once from the following adapter .

```
public class mAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {



public mAdapter (Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MusicPlaylist");
            return query;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_music, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);



    //Audio retrieving
    final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    final ParseFile fileObject = object.getParseFile("music");

**// here I put a loop because I want it to download a list of audios at once and I think here is the problem**

    if (fileObject != null) {
        for (int i = 10; i >= j; j++) {
            new DownloadMusicfromInternet().execute(fileObject.getUrl());
        }

        fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {


            @Override
            public void done(byte[] bytes, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {


                    }//end on click
                }//end listener
                );

            }//end done
        });//end get data


    }//end if

        return v;
    }//end getItem View


}//end mAdapter
```

Any help would be appreciated ..

Comment: You'll potentially get better help if you can state a more clear question.

Comment: @JeffWolski  I have edited my question . what do you think , better now ?

Comment: @AdamahNour  i would recommend you to use a service to download heavy data using android default download manager class and save them on sd card. Async  thread is not a good way, as it halts the UI of your app for long time, and no user will wait long to use app.

Comment: @Dev can you illustrate more please .. what do you mean by service .. any example ?